# how can i create dynamic panel for news in sharepoint 2010

Tags: database, dynamic, sharepoint-2010

sharepoint is Hectic.

in web developer program (like asp with c#) we can create a panel with dynamic element in it.
but in sharepoint I'm Confused.

problem :

i need create a panel for newest news in my sharepoint site that automatically update when a news added.
in asp.net (or similar) I would add one grid view and connected it to a database table.
but here i don`t know What should I do.

1: from What controls should I use
2: how connect this controls to Database Table

thankful

Answer (score 0):

You can create a WebPart (and use ASP.NET web form controls in it) and link these to a list.
The list itself can be linked to an external datasource (like your table) if needed.

Cheers,

Karel